# is there a way to write if (x div sqrt(x)=sqrt(x)) because it does not work

Tags: pascal

I want to insert a number an the program tells me whether the number is a square of a natural number or not. So far it says that something is wrong in **if (x div sqrt(x)=sqrt(x))**

```
program Naturalnumbers;  
var  
  x : integer;  
begin  
  writeln ( ' is the inserted number a square of a natural number? ' );  
  readln (x); 

  if (x div sqrt(x)=sqrt(x)) then   
    writeln( 'yes' )  
  else  
    writeln('no' )  

  readln;  
end;
```

Comment: Hey! I have a few suggestions on how to improve your question, which will get someone to answer it quickly. First, in the title, enter a description of the problem, and only state the question in the body. Also, include a slightly longer description of what you are trying to do and what error / unwanted behavior you are getting when you tried what you've tried. Second, mark all your source code as such. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You try to do  `x div sqrt(x)` where `x` is an `Integer`. 
The `Sqrt` function returns an `Extended`. That's a floating point number. The `div` operator is a division for `Integer` numbers. So it can't be used here.

You can store the returned value of `Sqrt` in an `Extended` variable. Then you can cut off the part behind the decimal separator using [Trunc](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/trunc.html), [Ceil](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/ceil.html) or [Floor](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/floor.html) and store the value in another `Integer` variable to multiply it later with itself and compare it with `x`. That looks like this:

```
program project1;

var
  x, truncatedSquareRoot : integer;
  squareRoot: extended;

begin
  writeln ( ' is the inserted number a square of a natural number? ' );
  readln (x);

  squareRoot := sqrt(x);
  truncatedSquareRoot := Trunc(squareRoot);

  if ((truncatedSquareRoot * truncatedSquareRoot) = x) then
    writeln( 'yes' )
  else
    writeln('no' );

  readln;
end.
```

It's useful to store the result of an expensive calculation like `Sqrt` in a variable to avoid doing it twice.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done faster in one code line and without extra variables: Just compare the `sqrt` result with its truncated value. For example:

for `x=64`: `sqrt(64)=8`, `trunc(sqrt(64))=8`, => `(sqrt(64) = trunc(sqrt(64))) = true`;

for `x=65`: `sqrt(65)=8,062...`, `trunc(sqrt(65))=8`, => `(sqrt(65) = trunc(sqrt(65))) = false`;

```
program Naturalnumbers;  
var  
  x : integer;  
begin  
  writeln ( ' is the inserted number a square of a natural number? ' );  
  readln (x); 

  if trunc(sqrt(x))=sqrt(x) then   
    writeln( 'yes' )  
  else  
    writeln('no' )  

  readln;  
end;
```

Or even without `if then else` statement.

```
program Naturalnumbers;
var
  x: integer;
const
  Answ: array [False .. True] of string = ('No', 'Yes');
begin
  writeln(' is the inserted number a square of a natural number? ');
  readln(x);
  write(Answ[trunc(sqrt(x)) = sqrt(x)]);
  readln
end;
```

Comment: This is actually the same approach like mine. I'm using variables to make it easier for beginners. I assume the OP is a beginner.

Comment: @Wosi I would be glad to agree, but I can't. You code of course works, but you make an unnecessary multiplication of `CeiledSquareRoot` and compare it with `x` (this may confuse the beginner). My answer trains the OP to deal with numbers (the function's result) instead. In addition my code shows the underlying answer to the question: _How to know that a number is natural?_ That was the reason for posting my answer and explanation. Sorry if I offended you!

Comment: No, of course, you didn't offend me. I do the the multiplication because its faster than calculating the square root two times.

Comment: @Wosi Though, It is very clear that your code has an advanage before mine - you calculate `sqrt` only once (and use a variable to store the result). So I conclude that both answers (should they be understood by OP) will be useful for him. I upvote your answer.

Comment: @Wosi It seems the OP needs to finally understand that it would be most effective to strore the `SomeVar:=sqrt(x);` as you did and then do the numbers processing with `SomeVar` from my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer. I hope to got you right. If not feel free to edit it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The first error in the line

```
 if (x div sqrt(x)=sqrt(x)) then
```

is that the precedence of the '=' operator is greater than that of the div operator. So the compiler thinks you are asking

```
 if (x div (sqrt(x) = sqrt(x)) then
```

which is the equivalent of

```
 if (x div TRUE) then
```

instead of

```
 if ((x div sqrt(x)) = sqrt(x)) then
```

But even the latter would have an error because the div operator wants two integers to work with, while the sqrt function returns a floating point number. You can check this by trying to compile a line such as

```
 y := x div 0.1
```

for which the compiler will still complain.

So you could 'fix' things by replacing the div with a / to write

```
 if ((x / sqrt(x)) = sqrt(x)) then
```

This will compile, but it is still not guaranteed to provide the correct answer as the sqrt function will have round-off errors that may produce errors. The other answers provided by Wosi and asd-tm cover those issues.